# How to resolve UnboundLocalError: local variable referenced before assignment?

Tags: python

i keep getting a 'bad input' error message on my code

```
seq = 'ATGAAACGCATTAGCACCACCATTACCACCACCATCACCATTACCACAGGTAACGGTGCGGGCTGA'

def translate(seq):
    table = { 
        'ATA':'I', 'ATC':'I', 'ATT':'I', 'ATG':'M', 'ACA':'T', 'ACC':'T', 'ACG':'T', 'ACT':'T', 'AAC':'N', 'AAT':'N', 'AAA':'K', 'AAG':'K', 'AGC':'S', 'AGT':'S', 'AGA':'R', 'AGG':'R', 'CTA':'L', 'CTC':'L', 'CTG':'L', 'CTT':'L', 'CCA':'P', 'CCC':'P', 'CCG':'P', 'CCT':'P', 'CAC':'H', 'CAT':'H', 'CAA':'Q', 'CAG':'Q', 'CGA':'R', 'CGC':'R', 'CGG':'R', 'CGT':'R', 'GTA':'V', 'GTC':'V', 'GTG':'V', 'GTT':'V', 'GCA':'A', 'GCC':'A', 'GCG':'A', 'GCT':'A', 'GAC':'D', 'GAT':'D', 'GAA':'E', 'GAG':'E', 'GGA':'G', 'GGC':'G', 'GGG':'G', 'GGT':'G', 'TCA':'S', 'TCC':'S', 'TCG':'S', 'TCT':'S', 'TTC':'F', 'TTT':'F', 'TTA':'L', 'TTG':'L', 'TAC':'Y', 'TAT':'Y', 'TAA':'*', 'TAG':'*', 'TGC':'C', 'TGT':'C', 'TGA':'*', 'TGG':'W'} 
    
    if len(seq)%3 == 0: 
        for i in range(0, len(seq), 3): 
            codon = seq[i:i + 3] 
            protein+= table[codon] 
    return protein


translate(seq)
```

### Error:

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnboundLocalError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-1a7a95bb03f2> in <module>
----> 1 translate(seq)

<ipython-input-22-0ec1b5bc03cb> in translate(seq)
      6         for i in range(0, len(seq), 3):
      7             codon = seq[i:i + 3]
----> 8             protein+= table[codon]
      9     return protein

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'protein' referenced before assignment
```

Answer (score 1):

You are forgetting to initialize the variable `protein`, that is why you are getting that error.

```
seq = 'ATGAAACGCATTAGCACCACCATTACCACCACCATCACCATTACCACAGGTAACGGTGCGGGCTGA'

def translate(seq):
    table = { 
        'ATA':'I', 'ATC':'I', 'ATT':'I', 'ATG':'M', 'ACA':'T', 'ACC':'T', 'ACG':'T', 'ACT':'T', 'AAC':'N', 'AAT':'N', 'AAA':'K', 'AAG':'K', 'AGC':'S', 'AGT':'S', 'AGA':'R', 'AGG':'R', 'CTA':'L', 'CTC':'L', 'CTG':'L', 'CTT':'L', 'CCA':'P', 'CCC':'P', 'CCG':'P', 'CCT':'P', 'CAC':'H', 'CAT':'H', 'CAA':'Q', 'CAG':'Q', 'CGA':'R', 'CGC':'R', 'CGG':'R', 'CGT':'R', 'GTA':'V', 'GTC':'V', 'GTG':'V', 'GTT':'V', 'GCA':'A', 'GCC':'A', 'GCG':'A', 'GCT':'A', 'GAC':'D', 'GAT':'D', 'GAA':'E', 'GAG':'E', 'GGA':'G', 'GGC':'G', 'GGG':'G', 'GGT':'G', 'TCA':'S', 'TCC':'S', 'TCG':'S', 'TCT':'S', 'TTC':'F', 'TTT':'F', 'TTA':'L', 'TTG':'L', 'TAC':'Y', 'TAT':'Y', 'TAA':'*', 'TAG':'*', 'TGC':'C', 'TGT':'C', 'TGA':'*', 'TGG':'W'} 
    protein = '' # This line will solve the problem
    if len(seq)%3 == 0: 
        for i in range(0, len(seq), 3): 
            codon = seq[i:i + 3] 
            protein+= table[codon] 
    return protein
```

Now if you call

```
translate(seq)
```

The output will be:

```
'MKRISTTITTTITITTGNGAG*'
```

Answer (score 1):

well for one thing, that func. refers protein before assignment, I would add a line such as:

```
protein =''
```

to assign it to an empty str. right before

```
protein+= table[codon]
```

does it fix your problem?

Answer (score 0):

- As stated in the error `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'protein' referenced before assignment`, the variable `protein` does not yet exist when `protein += table[codon]` tries to assign a value to `protein` (i.e. `protein = protein + table[codon]`)
- The simplest way to resolve the error, is to initialize the variable as `protein = ''`
- The logic of the function remains unchanged.

```py
def translate(seq):
    protein = ''
    table = { 
        'ATA':'I', 'ATC':'I', 'ATT':'I', 'ATG':'M', 'ACA':'T', 'ACC':'T', 'ACG':'T', 'ACT':'T', 'AAC':'N', 'AAT':'N', 'AAA':'K', 'AAG':'K', 'AGC':'S', 'AGT':'S', 'AGA':'R', 'AGG':'R', 'CTA':'L', 'CTC':'L', 'CTG':'L', 'CTT':'L', 'CCA':'P', 'CCC':'P', 'CCG':'P', 'CCT':'P', 'CAC':'H', 'CAT':'H', 'CAA':'Q', 'CAG':'Q', 'CGA':'R', 'CGC':'R', 'CGG':'R', 'CGT':'R', 'GTA':'V', 'GTC':'V', 'GTG':'V', 'GTT':'V', 'GCA':'A', 'GCC':'A', 'GCG':'A', 'GCT':'A', 'GAC':'D', 'GAT':'D', 'GAA':'E', 'GAG':'E', 'GGA':'G', 'GGC':'G', 'GGG':'G', 'GGT':'G', 'TCA':'S', 'TCC':'S', 'TCG':'S', 'TCT':'S', 'TTC':'F', 'TTT':'F', 'TTA':'L', 'TTG':'L', 'TAC':'Y', 'TAT':'Y', 'TAA':'*', 'TAG':'*', 'TGC':'C', 'TGT':'C', 'TGA':'*', 'TGG':'W'} 
    
    if len(seq)%3 == 0: 
        for i in range(0, len(seq), 3): 
            codon = seq[i:i + 3] 
            protein += table[codon] 
    return protein 


# call the function
translate(seq)

[out]:
'MKRISTTITTTITITTGNGAG*'
```

### Alternate implementation

- Use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to group every `n`, `3` in this case, values together, then [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) them to the `values` in `table`.

  - The original function iterates through each group of 3, matches it to `table`, and adds the value to `protein`.
  - The new function creates all the groups at once, and then matches them all at once.
- [`''.join()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) creates a string of the mapped values.

```py
def translate(seq: str, n: int) -> str:
    table = {'ATA':'I', 'ATC':'I', 'ATT':'I', 'ATG':'M', 'ACA':'T', 'ACC':'T', 'ACG':'T', 'ACT':'T', 'AAC':'N', 'AAT':'N', 'AAA':'K', 'AAG':'K', 'AGC':'S', 'AGT':'S', 'AGA':'R', 'AGG':'R', 'CTA':'L', 'CTC':'L', 'CTG':'L', 'CTT':'L', 'CCA':'P', 'CCC':'P', 'CCG':'P', 'CCT':'P', 'CAC':'H', 'CAT':'H', 'CAA':'Q', 'CAG':'Q', 'CGA':'R', 'CGC':'R', 'CGG':'R', 'CGT':'R', 'GTA':'V', 'GTC':'V', 'GTG':'V', 'GTT':'V', 'GCA':'A', 'GCC':'A', 'GCG':'A', 'GCT':'A', 'GAC':'D', 'GAT':'D', 'GAA':'E', 'GAG':'E', 'GGA':'G', 'GGC':'G', 'GGG':'G', 'GGT':'G', 'TCA':'S', 'TCC':'S', 'TCG':'S', 'TCT':'S', 'TTC':'F', 'TTT':'F', 'TTA':'L', 'TTG':'L', 'TAC':'Y', 'TAT':'Y', 'TAA':'*', 'TAG':'*', 'TGC':'C', 'TGT':'C', 'TGA':'*', 'TGG':'W'} 
    if len(seq)%3 == 0:
        groups = [seq[s:s+n] for s in range(0, len(seq), n)]  # create a list with groups of 3 from the sequence
        protein = ''.join(map(table.get, groups))  # map the dict values to groups
        return protein


translate(seq, 3)
[out]:
'MKRISTTITTTITITTGNGAG*'
```